# Xlwings 'pictures.add()' returns error "got an unexpected keyword argument 'anchor'"

Tags: python, xlwings

I tried to use python's xlwings module yesterday to add some pictures to Excel, however the code returns an error.
The error states that `ws.pictures.add()` does not have the parameter called `"anchor"`, even though it does.

I'm totally confused and hope someone could help me determine why this problem occurs, thanks.

Screenshot showing Error Message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZzel.png)

The sample code is here:

```
import xlwings as xw 
from pathlib import Path

my_dir=Path(__file__).parent
e_dir=my_dir /'practice_accessories_3_1677117628091_20230223\图片更新删除.xlsx'
p_dir=my_dir/'practice_accessories_3_1677117628091_20230223\img'

wb=xw.Book(e_dir)
ws=wb.sheets['Sheet1']
i=1
for p in p_dir.glob('A*.png'):
    r=ws.range(i,1)
    r.row_height=30
    ws.pictures.add(p,anchor=r,height=30)
    i+=1
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

Comment: `anchor` is not a valid keyword. what were you expecting ?

Comment: `anchor` is a valid argument for [pictures.add](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/pictures.html) and it looks like the code would work. From the release notes  `anchor` was included for `pictures.add` in [v0.24.3 (Jul 15, 2021)](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html#older-releases) so if you don't have at least that version it wont be there. What version of Xlwings are your using?

Comment: Thank you so much.I just found that my xlwings version is 0.23.1, that is the case. After upgrading my xlwings, the error disappeared. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`anchor` is a valid argument for [pictures.add](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/pictures.html) and it looks like the sample code would work.
From the Xlwings release notes `anchor` was included for `pictures.add` in [v0.24.3 (Jul 15, 2021)](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html#older-releases) so if you don't have at least that version it wont be there.

What version of Xlwings are you using?